# How can I calculate the total return of my portfolio when it is rebalanced annually?

Tags: portfolio

I have a portfolio and I rebalanced it every year.
The portfolio return is 6%, 8%, 3% in years 1,2,3.
How can I calculate the total return of the portfolio?

Comment: It depends if you have contribution of new funds during those 3 years, or just a lump sum investment at the beginning of year 1.

Comment: I'm using a market-cap weighted portfolio. I directly invest a lump sum at the beginning of year 1 and I liquidate the portfolio at the end of year 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The total return for lump sum investment is (1.06 * 1.08 * 1.03) - 1 = 0.179144 = 17.91%

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I will try to explain my exercise better so that I can be sure that this is the right solution. I don't know the amount invested, but thanks to the market value I know the weights of the 3 stocks I have in my portfolio. I then multiply the return of each stock by its weight and the sum of the 3 gives me the return of my portfolio. Once I have found the return every year, I apply the formula you wrote and find the total return of the portfolio. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, just remember that the weights at the beginning of Year 1 should be used for the weighted return of each stock for Year 1.